# PHP access images with utf-8 encode

Tags: php, encoding

I have used scrapy(a python crawler framework), I crawled some images and dowload them,also I store the image online url in mysql table and after download I store the local path into mysql.now there is one problem, when I try to display the image with php, it can't access the image...it just display **404*
my mysql table：

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand       | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| series      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commodity   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| designer    | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year        | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| technology  | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| local_url   | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| downloaded  | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| referer     | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I use **url** field store the online image url and **local_url** field store the local image path.
some data in **local_url** is as following:

```
agape/— Contenitori/EVO-N\_NIVIS\_ALTO.jpg?1415875406,agape/— Contenitori/EVO-N\_CONTENITORE.jpg?1415875446,agape/— Contenitori/FLAT\_XL\_CONT\_PUZZLE.jpg?1415875463,agape/— Contenitori/EVOLUZIONE\_CONT\_PUZZLE.jpg?1415875485
```

I user comma to split the image path, the image stored in local is as following:

```
/var/www/images/agape/— Contenitori/xxx.jpg
```

the path contains space and other special charater,when I using php get the image from database and try to access the image,it can not be accessed..
the url try to access is as following:

```
http://45.32.255.165/images/agape/%E2%80%94%20Contenitori/EVO-L_660_PART_CASSETTO_R.jpg?1362501749
```

hope I describe my question clearly......

Comment: if the image is stored as `- Cartesio`, then telling the browser to hit `- Contenitori` isn't going to help much. e.g. it's "the image is stored in location X", and then pointing the browser at "location Y".

Comment: @MarcB sorry, it seems I give a wrong example, I edit the problem,please check it...